# Turn rows into columns for pandas dataframe if certain conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
|Var1 | Var2  | Method      | Category|
|-------------------------------------|
| A   |   1   | check       | cat1    |
| A   |   1   | check       | cat2    |
| B   |   2   | check       | cat1    |
| B   |   2   | creditcard  | cat2    |
```

where Method can only be either check or creditcard, and the Category is also limited to just two possible categories.

Whenever "Method" is the same for a given Var 1 and Var 2, I'd like to combine the two category rows into columns, like so:

```
|Var1 | Var2  | Method    |  Cat1 | Cat2 |
|----------------------------------------|
| A   |   1   | check     |  cat1 | cat2 |
| B   |   2   | check     |  cat1 | NaN  |
| B   |   2   | creditcard|  NaN  | cat 2|
```

Is this even possible?  I'd tried various groupby/pivoting/index reset arrangements, but nothing worked.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

One way using  `groupby` create the `join` string , then it is `get_dummies` problem

```
s=df.groupby(['Var1','Var2','Method'])['Category'].\
     apply(','.join).str.get_dummies(',')
s=s*s.columns
s.reset_index(inplace=True)
s
  Var1  Var2      Method  cat1  cat2
0    A     1       check  cat1  cat2
1    B     2       check  cat1      
2    B     2  creditcard        cat2
```

Comment: Tried to do this with `str.split(',',expand=True)`, but then `cat2` will be in the wrong column, it will be in `Cat1` column.

Comment: I think you can just stop in the first line with `reset_index()` at the end. Since the column title is `cat1` and `cat2`, maybe its better to have `1` and `0` as values... you gain `int dtype` advantages and reduce redundancy